# Mouseenter and mouseleave events in Safari browser

Tags: jquery, safari

I am trying to use jQuery to wire up some simple mouse events in a menu page. It works beautifully in Chrome and IE9 but in Safari the highlighting gets stuck on some elements as I move the mouse around. Here are the 3 browsers with the page displayed. You will have to imagine this since I was not permitted to post the link to the screen shot. Sorry.

Here is the code that wires up the events:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#number").focus();

    // We use td elements instead of anchors as the menu items. The ones we want to work with all have 
    // a custom attribute called url that stores the url template...
    var linkCells = $("td[url]");

    // Wire up the click handler for each link cell...
    linkCells.click(function () {
        Navigate($(this).attr('url'));
    });

    // Wire up mouse events for the link cells. We want to highlight the current cell and update
    // the number label...
    linkCells.bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
        var linkCell = $(this);
        linkCell.toggleClass('linkOn');
        if(e.type == 'mouseenter') {
            $("#numberLabel").html('<b>' + linkCell.attr('numberLabel') + '</b>');
        }
    });

    // Wire up the submit event in case the user presses the Enter key instead of clicking a link...
    $("#Form1").submit(function() {
        Navigate($("#lastLink").val());
        return false;
    });
});
```

Are there any special tricks that will make Safari behave the same as the other browsers?

Thanks,

Matthew MacFarland

Comment: Have you tried using hover? (http://api.jquery.com/hover/) is the same behavior happening?

Comment: could you create a simple jsfiddle to test on safari please?

Comment: Post a link to your screenshot.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Hg3Qn/ works fine at least

Comment: Here is my screen shot link: https://picasaweb.google.com/111442666405785730863/Screenshots#5756138958587218802

Comment: @ThomasClayson - I tried hover but that has a different problem in Safari. After I click on the cells the highlighting becomes stuck and won't clear when I leave that cell. hover works perfect in IE and Chrome.

Comment: Correction. It's the same problem whether I use hover or the mouseenter and mouseleave events. After I click one of the cells in Safari the highlight class linkOn does not clear. In fact if I then mouse over the same cell again the class does clear. It's like the toggle got reversed for the cells that get clicked. This does not happen in the other browsers.

Comment: Through a little trial and error I found that this works OK on Safari but I don't know why really. It's not the cleanest way to program it I think:

Comment: // Wire up mouseover event for the link cells. We want to highlight the current cell and update
                // the number label...
                linkCells.mouseover(function() {
                    var linkCell = $(this);
                    linkCell.addClass('linkOn');
                    $("#numberLabel").html('<b>' + linkCell.attr('numberLabel') + '</b>');
                });

                // Remove the highlighting when the mouse is out...
                linkCells.mouseout(function() {
                    $(this).removeClass('linkOn');
                });